# Is possible to read FireDAC MemTable on Python?

Tags: delphi, firedac, fdmemtable

I have some binaries (.adb) that is created in FireDAC Project, but i want to read the data in python, is there any documentation on how to read this format? I know it is a proprietary format, but the only way i consume the data is using Delphi?

Comment: Why not just get FireDAC to load the file then write it out to an XML file?

Comment: I'm python developer and i have zero experience in Delphi/Pascal, i only need the read the data, but you suggest create a program that i pass the adb file and then output the format that i need? So then i can call on my python program?

Comment: Do you have the Delphi app that creates the .adb files?

Comment: No, i only have the .adb, i managed to open them in C ++ Builder, is even possible to export to other formats.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no console application that performs this type of conversion.

Comment: Basically you need a [`TFDMemTable`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDMemTable) object, call [`LoadFromFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.LoadFromFile) on it, then [`SaveToFile()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.SaveToFile).

Comment: See [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/FireDAC.TFDMemTable.Main_Sample) and the associated [sample project](https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio10.3Demos/tree/master/Object%20Pascal/Database/FireDAC/Samples/Comp%20Layer/TFDMemTable/Main).